# Bash while loop with done < $1

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm a bit confused by the `done < $1` notation.

I'm trying to write a program "sumnums" that reads in a file called "nums" that has a couple rows of numbers. Then it should print out the rows of the numbers followed by a sum of all the numbers.

Currently I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0;
while read myline
do  
  echo "Before for; Current line: \"$myline\""
done
for i in $myline; do  
  sum=$(expr $sum + $i)
done < $1    
echo "Total sum is: $sum"
```

and it outputs the list of the numbers from nums correctly then says 
`./sumnums: line 10: $1: ambiguous redirect`, then outputs `Total sum is: 0`.

So somehow it isn't adding.  How do I rearrange these lines to fix the program and get rid of the "ambiguous redirect"?

Comment: How are you invoking your script?  Either call it as `./sumnum nums` or change `done < $1` to `done < nums`.

Comment: `cat nums | ./sumnums`

Comment: script needs the file as the argument.

Comment: Uhhh. You'll want to redirect stdin for the `while read` loop, not the `for` loop.

Comment: BTW, consider running scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ as a matter of course before asking about them here.

Comment: Also, consider reading through [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?").

Comment: @themightyscot, btw, in general, `./sumnums <nums` is much more efficient than `cat nums | ./sumnums`. In the former, you're giving `sumnums` direct access to the file `nums`; in the latter, you're forcing `sumnums` to read the output from a second program (`cat`), and only giving that separate/distinct software access to the input file.

Comment: ...that said, if you don't actually run `./sumnums nums`, passing `nums` in `$1`, there *is* no filename in `$1`, so `<"$1"` doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your filename is in `$1` (that is, that your script was called with `./yourscript nums`):

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 ]] || set -- nums  ## use $1 if already set; otherwise, override with "nums"

sum=0
while read -r i; do      ## read from stdin (which is redirected by < for this loop)
  sum=$(( sum + i ))     ## ...treat what we read as a number, and add it to our sum
done <"$1"               ## with stdin reading from $1 for this loop
echo "Total sum is: $sum"
```

If `$1` doesn't contain your filename, then use something that *does* contain your filename in its place, or just hardcode the actual filename itself.

Notes:

- `<"$1"` is applied to a `while read` loop. This is essential, because `read` is (in this context) the command that actually consumes content from the file. It **can** make sense to redirect stdin to a `for` loop, but only if something inside that loop is reading from stdin.
- `$(( ))` is modern POSIX sh arithmetic syntax. `expr` is legacy syntax; don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i} END{print "Total sum is: " sum}' file
```

`bash` is not the right tool for this task.

Comment: Where is the "done <" documented? What is the meaning of the "<" in bash? Does it have a name such as "redirect," under which its documentation can be found?

Comment: @JacobWegelin If I knew a simple explanation I would provide it, but I'm figuring it out too. Here's a link to [some documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Find this line: `done < <(route -n)  
#    ^ ^  First < is redirection, second is process substitution.`